# Black Area in skybox in opengl

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, skybox

Hi I am using opengl and I am having a problem if I go further from the skybox with the camera I get black areas, a smaller radius of the skybox will make the camera too close to the object to stay inside the skybox and increasing it obviously doesn't help.
:
[image: Here is a picture of the scene from one view]
 [image: and this is when viewing it from the back]

Here is the code for the skybox:

```
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPushMatrix();
    qobj = gluNewQuadric();
    glTranslated(50,0,0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, underwater);
    gluQuadricTexture(qobj,true);
    gluQuadricNormals(qobj,GL_SMOOTH);
    gluSphere(qobj,100,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: perhaps your far on the projection is too small?

Comment: @Sidar can you clarify?

Comment: Have you tried the link given by @LeComteduMerde-fou ? Basically your sphere goes beyond the frustum of your "camera"

Comment: I added the  glDepthRange (1, 1); before drawing the skybox but everything turned black.

Comment: You probably have to reset it after drawing your sphere. It's also mentioned in that link.

Comment: If I do that i get a black skybox and the other objects are visible.

Comment: @Sidar any ideas?

Comment: Probably the sky"box"/skysphere goes past the far clipping plane. If you don't know what a far clipping plane is, look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using GLU.
You probably use it for the projection matrix too.

You need to double the 'far' value that you pass into [gluPerspective](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

Comment: doing that makes the scene go inside the skybox :/

Comment: nvm that actually worked!!!! Thank you very much! :D